# mv ,,, to *?

Tags: linux

I tried something on my vm ubuntu and managed to mess it up... luckily I made a snapshot not too long a go.

I renamed a file to `,,,` and tried to `mv ,,, *`. The entire content of the dir disappeared. 
Can someone please explain to me what happened?

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for a seriously "WTF" command. seewiously. ",,," is apparently a legal filename but just seems like a bad idea. Then lets move it to '*'. XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell expands `*` into the entire contents of the current directory (modified by shell options). If the last entry in the current directory is itself a directory, then everything will be moved into that directory.

Comment: Awesome "what if" question :-)